# Double expectation definition and conditional expectation

Tags: probability

For two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, we can define $E(X\mid Y)$ to be the function of $Y$ that satisfies
$$E(Xg(Y)) = E(E(X\mid Y)g(Y))$$
for any function $g$. Using this definition show that $$E((X_1 + X_2)\mid Y ) = E(X_1\mid Y ) + E(X_2\mid Y).$$

Rrying to use the definition given I did:
$$E((X_1+X_2)\mid Y) = E((E(X_1\mid Y) + E(X_2\mid Y))\mid Y)$$
but then how do I continue from there?

Answer (score 1):

Let $h_i(Y) = E[X_i|Y]$.  What can you say about $E[\{h_1(Y)+h_2(Y)\}g(Y)]$?

Comment: Ohhh so you can move out the g(Y) and then it becomes g(Y)E[{h1(Y) + h2(Y)}] and then g(Y)[E(h1(Y)) + E(h2(Y))]... Am I moving in the right direction or did I misunderstand your comment? :/

Comment: No, not quite.  You cannot move out the $g(Y)$ in the unconditional expectation.  What important property of expectation do you know?